# Fitbit Scribe Token, can it be reused when running the program again?

Tags: scribe, fitbit

I have been successful creating a token and getting a secured resource from fitbit using Scribe.  Can I utilize the original requestToken and verifier to get an new Authentication token when I run the program again?  Or do I need to get the program authorized again?

If I can use the token how do you store it in Java so that it can be reused?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No you cant reuse the request token and verifier.Use them to get 'accesstoken and refresh token'(Oauth2) or 'key and secret' (Oauth1) and store them in Database. Then while trying to access users details , use these from db.

If it is giving the error 401 accesstoken expired , use refresh token to get new accessToken(Oauth2).